# Date inserted in 1900-01-01 format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

When i am insert date through ajax calenderExtender selected date format is '1900-01-01' is saved in Sql server 2008 database,

I want to save the date as selected date in database. Please help me..

Comment: Is the problem the format (ISO 6801, yyyy-mm-dd), that you store it as a string, or that it's 1900-01-01?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I wanted to store selected date like '07/13/2011' but when i am saving the date it store only '1900-01-01'.

Comment: You want to _present_ the data in a specific format. The stored format should be a datetime column/variables.

Comment: Do you mean that the value stored is "1900-01-01", or the format is "yyyy-mm-dd"? What data type is the column?

Comment: What i mean to say is the value is stored only '1900-01-01' but not the selected value

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in question?  Dates in Sql Server are not stored in any format.

Comment: Yes sir, got the answer,what u r saying is absolutely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *value* (not format) is '1900-01-01' and the column is date or datetime, then you are sending an empty string

An empty string casts to zero (int, float) or '01 Jan 1900' (date etc). This date is the "zero" date for SQL Server...

Comment: Let me send the code for datetime against the database. Please.